# How to add a global action with destination as an Activity in a navigation graph?

Tags: android, navigation

I have a nav graph. One of the destinations is an activity. How do I add a global action to reach that activity? I can add global actions for fragments but not activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home_nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/feedFragment2">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/feedFragment2"
        android:name="com.nooblabs.conduit.ui.FeedFragment"
        android:label="fragment_feed"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_feed">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_feedFragment2_to_userProfileActivity2"
            app:destination="@id/userProfileActivity" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_articleDetail"
            app:destination="@id/articleActivity" />
    </fragment>

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_feedFragment"
        app:destination="@id/feedFragment2" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
        android:name="com.nooblabs.conduit.ui.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="ProfileFragment" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_profileFragment"
        app:destination="@id/profileFragment" />
    <activity
        android:id="@+id/userProfileActivity"
        android:name="com.nooblabs.conduit.UserProfileActivity"
        android:label="UserProfileActivity"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_user_profile">
        <argument
            android:name="username"
            app:argType="string" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:id="@+id/articleActivity"
        android:name="com.nooblabs.conduit.ArticleActivity"
        android:label="ArticleActivity">
        <argument android:name="articleSlug" />
    </activity>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/searchFragment"
        android:name="com.nooblabs.conduit.ui.SearchFragment"
        android:label="fragment_search"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_search">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_search_to_userProfile"
            app:destination="@id/userProfileActivity" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_search_to_article"
            app:destination="@id/articleActivity" />
    </fragment>
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_searchFragment"
        app:destination="@id/searchFragment" />


</navigation>
```

I want to reach 'articleActivity' from anywhere in the graph using a global action.

Answer (score 1):

just use the activity id in the global action, similar to fragment

```
<action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_articleActivity"
        app:destination="@id/articleActivity" />
```